# trying to set session variable

Tags: php, mysql

```
if(isset($_SESSION['admin'])) {
echo "<li><b>Admin</b></li>";
}

<?php
session_name('MYSESSION');
session_set_cookie_params(0, '/~cgreenheld/');
session_start();

$conn = blah blah
$query2 = 'Select Type from User WHERE Username = "'.$_SESSION['user'].'" AND Type =\'Admin\'';
$result2 = $conn->query($query2);
if($result2->num_rows==1) {
$_SESSION['admin'] = $result2;
}
?>
```

Hi, I'm trying  to set this session variable but it doesn't seem to be setting, and i'm wondering if anyone can help. If session['admin'] isset it should echo the admin button.
But i'm not quite sure why? (I do have session start and everything on everypage, it's not a problem with that or any of the "You don't have php tags" I have checked the mysql query, and it does return something from my table. Any ideas please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `session_start();` should be at the top of the page before anything to do with the session variables.

From [the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php):

When session_start() is called or when a session auto starts, PHP will call the open and read session save handlers.

Edit from comments:

```
<?php
    session_name('MYSESSION');
    session_set_cookie_params(0, '/~cgreenheld/');
    session_start();
    // Moved to start after answer was accepted for better readability
    // You had the <?php after this if statement? Was that by mistake?
    if(isset($_SESSION['admin'])) 
    {
        echo "<li><b>Admin</b></li>";
    }

    // If you have already started the session in a file above, why do it again here?

    $conn = blah blah;
    $query2 = 'Select Type from User WHERE Username = "'.$_SESSION['user'].'" AND Type =\'Admin\'';
    // Could you echo out the above statement for me, just to 
    // make sure there aren't any problems with your sessions at this point?
    $result2 = $conn->query($query2);
    if($result2->num_rows==1) 
    {
        $_SESSION['admin'] = $result2;
        // It seems you are trying to assign the database connection object to it here.
        // perhaps try simply doing this:
        $_SESSION['admin'] = true;
    }
?>
```

Edit 2 from further comments:

You have to actually fetch the fetch the data like this - snipped from [this tutorial](http://www.php-mysql-tutorial.com/wikis/mysql-tutorials/retrieve-data-from-a-mysql-database.aspx) which might help you out some more:

```
$query  = "SELECT name, subject, message FROM contact";
$result = mysql_query($query);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
    echo "Name :{$row['name']} <br>" .
     "Subject : {$row['subject']} <br>" .
     "Message : {$row['message']} <br><br>";
}
```

But having said that, while we are talking about it, you would be better off moving away from the old `mysql_*` functions and move to [PDO](http://au.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) which is much better.

Comment: Check @courtney comment on my answer.

Comment: Select Type from User WHERE Username = "cgreenheld" AND Type ='Admin'

Comment: @courtney What about the comments inside the `if` statement?

Comment: okay so i set it too true, it will echo out admin on that page, but not on the rest of my pages?

Comment: @courtney have you added that code to all of your pages? Also double check the `session_start();`

Comment: the connect to the server and find out if its an admin?

Comment: @courtney In your other pages, are you perchance trying to see if the content of the is something specific? With my suggestion, I set it to `true`. In your code you weren't actually passing any data to it. If you wanted to put data from the database into the session, you would have to actually iterate through the results of the query.

Comment: when you say iterate through the reuslts of the query what do you mean exactly?

Answer (score 1):

Move `session_start();` to the top of the page. You are trying to retrieve sessions, where it's not loaded.

**EDIT:** Try echoing `$_SESSION['admin']`, if it even contains something. Also try debugging your `if($result2->num_rows==1)` code by adding `echo('its working');` or `die('its working');` inside it, to check if $result2 contains exactly 1 row, since currently it seems $result2 contains either more than 1 row or no rows at all.

Comment: these are in two separate files, i forgot to mention, and there is a session start for the top bit, the top bit is in a separate file

Comment: when i echo it's working, it echos its working, so i don't think it's assigning it the session variable

Comment: @courtney Have a look at the edit I made to my answer - especially the bit about what you assign to the session variable.

Comment: @courtney was it echoing $_SESSION['admin'] correctly or the text inside if statement?

Comment: I think the problem lies with `$result2 = $conn->query($query2);
` then `$_SESSION['admin'] = $result2;`. Setting it to a simple bool might do the trick instead. That's what seems to be getting checked later anyhow.